# Why Don't My IntelliJ Code Breakpoints Work?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run my tests on debug, the debugger stops on the test breakpoints, but not in the code itself. Why is that?

[image]

I have tried:

- Rebooting my machine
- Updating IntelliJ to the latest version
- Restarting the software and clearing the cache
- Deleting the debugger configurations
  None of that works.

I also notice that my System.out.println doesn't print to the console in neither the test nor the application code. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: Can you give us more details? It's hard to help you with just that. Add a screenshot with your breakpoints and describe clearly what you expect and what happens

Comment: Added a screenshot with debugger points that do and don't work

Comment: How do you deploy the application server? If it's deployed separatly, do you have a remote debug connection?

Comment: `I also notice that my System.out.println doesn't print to the console in neither the test nor the application code. Not sure if this is related` are you sure this code is actually execute? Whet Run Configuration do you use?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you found a solution to this?